# Detect if Local Storage has been edited by user?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I understand that local storage is a variable on the client side and they have full access to this information(edit delete etc). Is there a way to detect if a user has changed a value in local storage?

Comment: Proxy local storage access or create a hash of the local storage contents?

Comment: What are you trying to protect yourself from by checking this? You should already be assuming that everything the client's machine sends to your server has been compromised and verifying it is permitted server-side.

Comment: there is a "storage" event that fires when localStorage is changed. The one caveat is that it won't fire on the tab that made the change(except ie), but a hidden iframe can monitor and postMessage() any changes.

Comment: @PaulS. I'm debating on storing a high score for a simple game if the user hasn't logged. Obviously i'm not looking for anything bulletproof, but something to make it a little tougher for your average joe. As of right now i can open Chrome dev tools and jsut edit the value.

Comment: @RobertWMcElaney I'd say "the high score shown to the user doesn't matter", it only matters if they're submitting a fake high score to your server, and if that's the case, catching local storage changes isn't going to solve the problem

Comment: Yeah I agree with showing to the user, I was trying to avoid sharing fall high scores on social media.

Comment: @RobertWMcElaney What? That's crazy. Anybody can post whatever they want to social media. You can spend all the time in the world trying to secure the local store, and people can still just forge the social media message part with whatever value they want.

Comment: @meagar CRAZY! Well, yes you can post whatever you want to social media. I was thinking of going the route of dynamic image generation to social media.

Again, I'm not storing credit card numbers or anything,I was just investigating avenues to make it harder for your average user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some levels of protection offered - but you are right to be cautious. If you are worried you can encrypt or add checksums / md5s to see if data has been modified.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is absolutely nothing you can do. Whatever measures you might implement are themselves as utterly insecure as `localStorage` is in the first place. You *cannot* build security in JavaScript on top of a browser's fundamentally insecure JavaScript environment, and you cannot trust the content of `localStorage`. No amount of code will allow you to trust it. You must rethink whatever has led you to this solution.